# Using AddDataDialog in standalone ArcObjects/C# application?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, c#, arcobjects

I need some help with showing an "AddDataDialog" in a C# standalone application to select some feature classes from inside a file-geodatabase. Whatever I try, it ends up with an Exception which makes no sence to me. I used a ESRI snippet to provide the hWnd of  "this" application and a referenced bool.

[image]
Is it possible to use this Dialog out of the context of ArcMap? And, if yes, has someone out there an idea what I might have done wrong so far?

Comment: Are you used IAddDataDialog in a standalone program? beacuse of esri [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/IAddDataDialog_Interface/000v00000024000000/) this interface is available on desktop only.How you did that?
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API for the Interface [IAddDataDialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v00000024000000) it appears you need to set the Document property which you are not doing in the screen shot you supplied. May be that is the source of the problem?

In the walk through example on how to build a map viewing application they simply add a reference to the add data button to a toolbar, that may be a simpler approach?

```
axToolbarControl1.AddItem("esriControls.ControlsAddDataCommand",  - 1,  - 1, false, 0, esriCommandStyles.esriCommandStyleIconOnly);
```

Comment: The second approach is more effective indeed. And yes, the missing "Document" was the source my problem. Thank you!